# Googlesheet: Question from a beginner, how to use a formula to combine [transpose] functions by each 6 cells within a single column?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a daily task to change thousands data into a table, since it is repeatable, I wonder if there should be a easier way to use one formula instead of manually type rows of Transpose function just changing the index in the bracket. Would anyone happy to teach me please?

Here is a example sheet I made to show an example

[Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11yjGDlF_cWpqyR9JoiX3D26-h26tMt2bIlo4gI6hLKw/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not too bad using an array formula with Sequence:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(sequence(counta(A:A)/6,6),{row(A:A),A:A},2))
```

[image]

[image]

assuming number of rows divides exactly by 6 (as it does in this case)

otherwise

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(sequence(roundup(counta(A:A)/6),6),{row(A:A),A:A},2))
```

and also assuming data starts at row 1, otherwise you would need to change the start number of Sequence e.g. for data starting at row 2:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(sequence(roundup(counta(A:A)/6),6,2),{row(A:A),A:A},2))
```

Comment: Genius! I've been struggling with that.

Answer (score 1):

This goes in cell C1, then drag down the formula:

`=transpose(indirect(("$A"&(row($A1)*6)-5&":$A"&row($A1)*6)))`

I can't think of an easy way to get it in an `ARRAYFORMULA`.

Comment: Brilliant idea. Many thanks for your help, it really save me lots of time and avoid typing mistake. Although it may not be perfect answer, your answer is still enough and very helpful to me. Thanks again.

Comment: If you drag down too far, you get an error because the `indirect` targets a value out of range. Hopefully that doesn't cause you any problems.